# Count binary numbers of length $k$ such that they have specific number of substrings of length 2

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say we are given integer number $k$ and exactly $4$ other numbers $x_{00}, x_{01}, x_{10}, x_{11}$. We want to count binary numbers of length $k$, such that they start with $0$ and they have exactly $x_{00}$ substring of the form $00$, then $x_{01}$ substrings of the form $01$...

Substring is contiguous part of the whole number. For example $001$ is substring of $1001$.

I was thinking about solution with dynamic programming but I think that it will be very slow, so I started thinking about math formula, but I cannot come up with anything useful.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:  think of your string as a block of zeros, followed by a block of ones, followed by a block of zeros, etc.  A block can be as few as one bit.  Based on the $x$'s you are given how many transitions are there?  How many blocks of zeros?  How many blocks of ones?  Can you find a restriction on the $x$'s based on this?

How many total two bit substrings are there?  Can you find a restriction on the input data based on this?

If either of your restrictions are not met, you can answer zero without further effort.  Otherwise, what is the order of the $01$ substrings and the $10$ substrings?  Where can you scatter the remaining $0$s?  How many are there?  Similarly for the remaining $1$s.